# Let $W=\{p(t) \in P_2 | p(-t) = -p(t),$ for all $t \in R\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W=\{p(t) \in P_2 | p(-t) = -p(t),$ for all $t \in R\}$

Prove ,or disprove that $W$ is a subspace of $P_2$ If it is a subspace find a basis for $W$. Find $dim(W)$

heres what I have gathered: in order for $W$ to be a subspace then it must pass all 8 axioms, the 4 addition axioms and 4 scalar multiplication axioms

A1: $(u+v)+w = u+(v+w)$

A2: $v+w=w+v$

A3: there exists a vector $0$ such that $0+v=v$ for all $0$

A4: each $v\in V$ has an additive inverse such that $v+(-v)=0$

S1: $r(v+w)=rv+rw$

S2: $(r+s)v=rv+sv$

S3: $r(sv)=(rs)v$

S4: $1v=v$

intuitively i imagine that all of these would pass, but im a bit confused on how to show this with abstract polynomials, also intuitively $W$ does contain any second degree polynomials or $p(-t)\neq -p(t)$, so i would imagine that the basis would be something along the lines of $\{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\}$, and the $dim(W) = 2$? Thats really all ive been able to gather and its all just intuitive, meaning possibly completely wrong. any help setting up how to verify the axioms and maybe a brief explanation of the basis and dim of W is prob all i need to be able to handle this type of problem. so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P_2$ is a vector space, to show that $W$ is a subspace, you don't need to show the eight axioms. You only need to show the three properties for a subspace:

1. $\vec{0}\in W$;
2. $W$ is closed under addition;
3. $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

For the dimension or basis, using the fact that $p(-t)=-p(t)$ which means $at^2-bt+c=-(at^2+bt+c)$, what can you get?

Comment: The first one is even not necessary. It is a consequence of the last one.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: Yes, good point.